# Page Range in Bibliography Item without Modifying .bib Entry

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm pretty sure this must've been asked before, but I couldn't find it.

In this MWE, I'd like to have The LaTeX Companion appear in the bibliography, but with selected pages (e.g. "`pp. 155--162`") without having to edit its entry in the `.bib` file. Something like `\nocite[155-162]{companion}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent I'd like to have The \LaTeX\ Companion appear in the bibliography, but with selected pages (e.g. ``pp. 155--162'') without having to edit its entry in the \verb .bib \ file.

\nocite{companion}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the idea is that the bibliography entry shows the bibliographic data of your source. For more specific pinpoint references one usually uses the optional argument of `\cite` in the text.

I don't doubt that there are legitimate uses to adding pages to bibliography entries on the fly, but I can't think of a good reason at the moment that would not better be covered by a different approach.

Anyway, here is a hopefully robust implementation of a `\nocitepagestoentry[<pages>]{<entrykey>}`. Since we want to be able to add pages anywhere in the document (even after `\printbibliography`) we collect the pages we want to inject for each entry key and write them to the `.aux` file at the end of the document. This has the added advantage that we can inject the pages field when `biblatex` reads the entry data from the `.bbl` file so that from then on our injected pages are in the `pages` field.
(Because our injected '`pages`' field is not preprocessed by Biber/BibTeX we slightly alter the `pages` field format to take care of nice formatting.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\steveblx@pagesentries}{}

% I know it's a bit pointless to declare #1
% optional and then do nothing if it is not
% present, but that way we mirror the argument
% structure of \cite
% [<pages>]{<entrykey>}
\newcommand*{\nocitepagestoentry}[2][]{%
  \ifblank{#1}
    {}
    {\nocite{#2}%
     \ifinlist{#2}{\steveblx@pagesentries}
       {}
       {\listadd{\steveblx@pagesentries}{#2}}%
     \ifcsvoid{steveblx@addpages@#2}
       {\csdef{steveblx@addpages@#2}{#1}}
       {\csappto{steveblx@addpages@#2}{, #1}}}}

% write pages to aux file
\def\steveblx@writepages#1{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\steveblx@writepages@i
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {\csname steveblx@addpages@#1\endcsname}{#1}}

\def\steveblx@writepages@i#1#2{%
  \blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}
    {\string\steveblx@setpages{#2}{\unexpanded{#1}}}}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \forlistloop{\steveblx@writepages}{\steveblx@pagesentries}}

% read pages from aux file
\def\steveblx@setpages#1#2{%
  \csgdef{steveblx@savedpages@#1}{#2}}

% inject pages into 'pages' field
\def\steveblx@addpagesfield{\blx@bbl@fielddef{pages}}

\AtDataInput{%
  \ifundef\abx@field@pages
    {\ifcsvoid{steveblx@savedpages@\abx@field@entrykey}
       {}
       {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\steveblx@addpagesfield
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            {\csname steveblx@savedpages@\abx@field@entrykey\endcsname}}}
    {}}
\makeatother

% we need \mknormrange because the injected pages 'field' is not preformatted
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
I'd like to have The \LaTeX\ Companion appear in the bibliography,
but with selected pages (e.g. ``pp. 155--162'')
without having to edit its entry in the \verb|.bib| file.

\nocitepagestoentry[157-162]{companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. The LaTeX Companion. 1st ed. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley, 1994, pp. 157–162. 528 pp.]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, usually I'd go for the optional argument in `\cite`, but this work (or, more precisely, part thereof) that I'm citing is relevant to the a whole chapter, but not at a specific place. Since t I'd reuse the same bibliography entry over and over again (e.g. citing a different chapter of some handbook in each chapter of my document), I thought maybe I could avoid having to define a separate entry in the `.bib` file for each chapter. Your answer certainly helps me in doing that, but if you believe another approach is more appropriate, I'd be glad to hear your advice.

Comment: @steve If the part of the work you want to reference is a particular chapter of a book, I would look into `@inbook` 'child' entries. You would have to add a new entry to your `.bib` file (which you say you don't want), but you could keep duplication of data at a minimum by using `crossref = {companion},` in the `@inbook`. Other than that I would avoid injecting random page numbers into the bibliography unless your readers are aware that you want to point them to something. I don't know what kind of document you are writing. Adding page numbers might be OK and expected in a reading list. ...

Comment: ... But may go unnoticed in a normal bibliography in a maths paper, say. I'd find it much more useful as a reader to be pointed to relevant sections of a book in a short discussion/mention in the text. But this is all context-, field- and culture-dependent, so without knowing what you are actually doing I don't think I can give a useful suggestion. ...

Comment: ... And even if I knew what kind of document you have in mind and why you don't want to explicitly cite the work in your document itself (where you could easily give page references), I don't know if I could give you an answer that respects the culture in your field.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! And for pointing me to `crossref`, which I didn't know about, and will probably be what I end up using.