# Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a Error with natbib bibliography: empty bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

When I use this code:

```
\documentclass[portuges]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,lmargin=2.2cm,rmargin=2cm,bmargin=2.2cm}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Ref}

\end{document}
```

I keep getting:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Frid' on page 5 undefined on input line 167.

Package natbib Warning: Citation `artcl' on page 5 undefined on input line 173.

Package natbib Warning: Citation `cap' on page 5 undefined on input line 190.

(TPC_eletro.bbl
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again>
```

What am I doing wrong?
 My bib file looks like this:

```
@Book{Frid,
  author    = {Fridman, Alexander},
  publisher = {Taylor \& Francis},
  title     = {Plasma physics and engineering},
  year      = {2004},
  address   = {New York},
  isbn      = {1560328487},
  pages     = {559-560},
  pagetotal = {2},
}

@Article{artcl,
  author  = {Alice Hong},
  title   = {Dielectric Strength of Air},
  year    = {2000},
  comment = {An educational, fair use website},
  url     = {https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2000/AliceHong.shtml},
}

@Article{cap,
  title = {Cylindrical Capacitor},
  year  = {2006},
  url   = {http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capcyl.html#c2},
}

@Article{plast,
  journal = {Omnexus},
  title   = {Dielectric Constant},
  year    = {2015},
  comment = {An educational, fair use website},
  url     = {https://omnexus.specialchem.com/polymer-properties/properties/dielectric-constant},
}
```

And it was working perfectly fine without the `natbib` package.

Comment: Delete the temporary `.aux` and `.bbl` files. Then recompile with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...)

Comment: The entries `artcl`, `cap` and `plast` are strictly speaking not `@article`s. `@misc` would be more appropriate (with `plainnat`, other styles may define more specific types for online resources such as `@online` or `@electronic`). The `pagetotal = {2},` in `Frid` looks wrong and it is unusual to give a `page` field for `@book` entries (see for example my comment at the end of the answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/547181/35864).

Comment: I have tried deleting the files. Nothing changes...
I changed the entries type, thanks

Comment: Ah, I see now. You need to load the `url` package (`\usepackage{url}`) so the URL `http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capcyl.html#c2` from `caps` works. (If you want links in your document you can load `hyperref` [`\usepackage{hyperref}`] instead of `url`, because `hyperref` loads `url` automatically.)

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you are typesetting URLs in your document it is a good idea to load the `url` or `hyperref` package (load `url` if you only care about URLs, load `hyperref` if you want linked URLs and additional links in your document for example from `\ref` or in the table of contents; `hyperref` loads `url` so there is generally no need to load both).

If neither `url` nor `hyperref` is loaded, `natbib` uses a fallback definition to print URLs that can not deal with special characters like `#` properly. In case such a character appears in a URL you may get very cryptic error messages like the only quoted in the question.

```
\documentclass[portuges]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
% or
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{cap,
  title = {Cylindrical Capacitor},
  year  = {2006},
  url   = {http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capcyl.html#c2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citep{cap}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Nicely typeset bibliography entry with URL]